# How to find difference between two column in excel pivot

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerbi

I have a column in power pivot named "member_status" which contains the status of a member as "Joiner"and "Leaver". I have another column called Date which has join date and leave date. I wan't to see how many left how many joined and the difference between two in a pivot table. Can any one please guide to what i wants to achieve please.

Table structure.

```
Status       Date
Joiner     2017-11-31 00:00:00.000
Leaver     2017-09-30 00:00:00.000
Joiner     2017-02-11 00:00:00.000
Joiner     2017-03-26 00:00:00.000
Leaver     2017-10-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: And what's exactly stopping you in your original table / data range to create a new column, name it diff and do `[@[Leaver]] - [@[Joiner]]`, or it's respective `COUNTIF`  and then just use it as field for the pivot?

Comment: Here is my data, the problem is both joiner and leaver is in the same column and i get this data by taking status in column in pivot and data in row

Comment: @Rawrplus i cant use  [@[Leaver]] - [@[Joiner]] as both joiner and leaver under the same column

Comment: perhaps you should reconsider your table structure? Seems far more logical to treat it like an object. i.e. joining and leaving have their own individual properties and each customer has unique id. May be busywork now, but sounds like it will help a lot of your data-management in the future

Comment: You are right. I thought the same. Thanks alot. I will let you know once i structure the data.